# Can't have my app programatically send SMS if user doesn't use stock SMS app as default

Tags: android, smsmanager

I've read through the [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) about the changes made to using sending and receiving SMS in your app.  I've also read through various discussions and answers on this site and others.  However, I'm still not entirely clear on how this all works today.  I use the following code to send an SMS in my app (used for some simple user verification):

```
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "sms verification", null, null);
                        SMSReceiver smsReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
                        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
```

I have a BroadcastReceiver with the following onReceive method:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null){

                SmsMessage[] messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage message = messages[i];
                    String phNum = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    phNum = phNum.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                    Log.i("SMSReceiver", "phone="+phNum);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

During development, this worked fine on my phone (LG G3 running 4.4.2).  However, when I distributed the app to a few friends, the app never made it out of the sending phase of the code.  He has his default app set to Hangouts, but the app was trying (unsuccessfully) to send this message through the stock Android SMS app.  The send kept failing and thus it never even made it to the BroadcastReceiver.

I didn't think I had to be the default messaging app to make this work, but I'm thinking now that that might be the point of this.  Is there a way to have my app pass a message to the default messaging app of the phone and also receive it in the BroadcastReceiver? I apologize if this is obvious from the existing documentation, but I just don't get it and I'm looking for a better explanation for why this would work on my phone running KitKat (with the stock SMS app as my default), but not on my friend's phone who's running Lollipop and using Hangouts as the default. Thanks!

Here's a screenshot showing that the phone is trying to send the message through the stock SMS app:

[image: screenshot of friend's sms error]

Comment: "the app was trying (unsuccessfully) to send this message through the stock Android SMS app" -- according to your code, the app isn't using any app, but instead is sending the SMS directly.

Comment: not exactly.  i don't redirect the user to the sms app, but the sms is sent through the stock sms app. that's where it's sending it from on mine and where it's trying to send it from on my friend's phone.  in any case, if that's the problem, then how would i specify to use the user's designated default messaging app? [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage) lead me to believe that sendTextMessage would take care of this for me

Comment: "This lead me to believe that sendTextMessage would take care of this for me" -- it should. "the sms is sent through the stock sms app" -- what is your evidence for this? Again, `SmsManager` does not send through any app.

Comment: Evidence: added a screenshot showing that the phone is trying to send the messages through the stock SMS app and failing

Comment: Unless this UI is popping up on its own, I would consider this simply demonstrating that your SMS is being logged in standard SMS `ContentProvider` locations, which many SMS clients will use. In particular, on Android 4.4+, those `ContentProviders` are actually officially sanctioned now.

Comment: Alright, fair enough, then why do you suppose the error?

Comment: Given that I have never used whatever device this is and have never seen this UI, my interpretation is that the device cannot send regular telephony SMS messages for some reason, which is why the messages show "retry" in the UI. As to why *that* is happening, I can't say.

Comment: The device for sure can send regular telephony messages.  We tested out just sending messages manually and it worked fine. I think it has to do with him having Hangouts set as his default messaging app, but I'm not sure, thus my question..Thanks for your input anyways

Comment: Hi! Did you found solution for this problem ? I have same problem( I must send sms in background.